# Angular slickgrid not allowing empty value with integer editor

Tags: angular, typescript, slickgrid

I have a column that is editable within my Angular SlickGrid. This column uses the packed Editors.Integer. Apparently it seems like I can't escape an active column without typing a number. I'm sure this can be fixed by setting a property or something alike. This is the initialized column:

```
  {
    id: 'quantity',
    name: 'Quantity',
    field: 'quantity',
    type: FieldType.number,
    editor: { 
      model:  Editors.integer
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @Alex, I assume you are refering to the lib [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) which I'm the author, if so then you should reference it in your SO question because most people won't know it. Also, if you like the lib, make sure to up vote (star) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If someone encounter something like this. What I did was to create a custom editor whom extended Editors.text and made a simple int validator with support for null values. Works like a charm.